# Eee PC 900 motherboard webcam header pinout

Tags: usb, webcam, connector, eee-pc

I have an old Eee PC 900 that I plan on modding.

I want to remove the webcam and connect a USB hub to its original connector.

The webcam connector on the motherboard has 4 pin and I'm sure its USB.
The webcam also has 4 conductors and the wires are orange, red, brown and black from left to right.

I'd like to have the pinout of the webcam motherboard connector so that I don't make a mistake resoldering the USB hub.

Answer (score 2):

If the webcam connector is really USB (which you can check using USBview.exe utility), it should have GND, D+, D-, and VBUS.

The GND pin must be easy to determine with any continuity tester. The VBUS must be 5V, which should be also easy to determine by any DMM.

The D+/D- wires you can simply connect at random, and see if it works. If not, swap them. Alternatively, if you have any minimal oscilloscope, you can check which wire comes to 3V  state first (for 100-400ms) after power-up (when the webcam is connected); it will be your D+.